# Finding quantity of mixture

Tags: percentages

In a mixture of milk and water, there is only $26$% water. After replacing the mixture with $7$ litres of pure milk, the percentage of milk in the mixture become $76$%. The quantity of mixture is

(a) 65 litre
(b) 91 litre
(c) 38 litre
(d) 87 litre
(e) none of these

**ATTEMPT**

Let mixture be of $x$ litres.Then water in mixture is $26x/100$ . After adding $7$ litres of milk in it ,it becomes $x+7$ litres and has $24$% water. So i get $24(x+7)/100 = 26x/100$ .Solving gives $x = 84$ .I am not sure though. Thanks for help

Comment: Yes, it's correct!

Comment: @EmilioNovati i cannot understand "mixture is replaced by 7 litres of pure milk" ? can you explain

Comment: Good point! Now I add an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we replace $7$ litres of the original mixture with $7$ litres of pure milk, we have that the final quantity of milk is:
$$
\dfrac{74}{100}(x-7)+7=\dfrac{76}{100}x
$$
Solving this equation we find $x$ that is the total (unchanged) quantity of mixture.

Comment: I did not get how you got left hand side

Comment: $74(x-7)/100$ is the quantity of milk from the remining original mixture.